# big query string concatenation of repeated and non repeated fields

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to do a string concatenation with both repeated and non-repeated fields in big query.

Lets say I have a table called events with the following data:

```
First_Name | Last_Name | Actions
 "Jane"    |    "Doe"  | ["walks", "jumps", "sits"]
 "Joe"     |   "Smith" |  ["walks", "sits"]
```

I want to create a new column that is an array that concatenates first name, last name, and action as a new column. This new column would have the same length as actions. It would look like this:

New Column

```
["Jane Doe walks", "Jane Doe jumps", "Jane Doe sits"]
["Joe Smith walks", "Joe Smith sits"]
```

The closest I got to this is

```
SELECT 
  *,
  ARRAY(SELECT concat(FIRST_NAME, " ", LAST_NAME) FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, array_length(Actions))))
FROM 
  events
```

This will give me a new column with two rows

```
["Jane Doe", "Jane Doe", "Jane Doe"]
["Joe Smith", "Joe Smith"]
```

how do I concat the action to this new column? And is there a cleaner way to do this altogether?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider below query

```sql
-- sample data
WITH events AS (
  SELECT  "Jane" First_Name, "Doe" Last_Name, ["walks", "jumps", "sits"] Actions
   UNION ALL
  SELECT  "Joe", "Smith", ["walks", "sits"]
)
-- query starts here
SELECT ARRAY(
         SELECT CONCAT(First_Name, ' ' , Last_Name, ' ', Action)
           FROM UNNEST(Actions) Action
       )
  FROM events;
```

**Query result**

[image]